# Google cloud functions using gcsfs - "RuntimeError: This class is not fork-safe"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've been using `gcsfs` in my Cloud Functions for a while now without issue. Suddenly, it has stopped working for newly deployed functions and is throwing an error:
`RuntimeError: This class is not fork-safe` (full traceback attached in photo)

I'm guessing it's due to one of the dependencies of the `gcsfs` package. In any case, I've updated `gcsfs` to current version in the `requirements.txt` and that has not helped.

The error can be reproduced by defining a cloud function as follows (Python 3.7):

main.py:

```
import gcsfs

# Read in runners and races for end_date
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='project-name-1234')

def try_gcsfs(request):

    with fs.open(r'any_csv_file_in_cloud_bucket.csv', 'rb') as f:
      lines = []
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line.decode(errors='ignore'))

    print('success')
```

requirements.txt:

```
gcsfs==2021.10.0
```

[image]

Comment: I had a grunge through the source code and found that the error message you are finding was introduced into fileystem spec code in March 2021 ... https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/pull/572/files

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue on my end and I also encountered the same runtime error `RuntimeError: This class is not fork-safe`. I already submitted a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/202804016). There's no guarantee for the ETA but hopefully this could be fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This change is related to the Python 3.7 buildpacks rollout. As a result of the move to `gunicorn` and its worker model, the global scope and function scope can be executed in separate processes. This issue can be fixed by moving the `GCSFileSystem` initialization into the function body.

You need to put `fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='project-name-1234')` inside the entrypoint `try_gcsfs`. Your code should look like this:

```
import gcsfs

def try_gcsfs(request):

  # Read in runners and races for end_date
  fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='project-name-1234')
    
  with fs.open(r'any_csv_file_in_cloud_bucket.csv', 'rb') as f:
    lines = []
      for line in f:
        lines.append(line.decode(errors='ignore'))

    print('success')
```

For more information, you may refer to this link, [Building Using the Pack CLI](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building/pack).